# Java code opens application and icon is displayed

Tags: java, image, image-processing, openimaj

When I use OpenIMAJ (using the `ImageUtilities.readMBF` code)(documentation [here](http://www.openimaj.org/openimaj-core-libs/core-image/apidocs/org/openimaj/image/ImageUtilities.html)) but also other type of code (related to image conversion) an icon is displayed in the mac dock

[image]

1) What is the cause of this strange behavior?

2) Is there a way to disable the icon opening? Or maybe a different code to use to avoid it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Any app that uses Java's `BufferedImage` class on the mac seems to do this by default, even if it doesn't open any windows. I think it's something to do with the way AWT initialises.

Anyway, assuming you're running from the command-line, the solution is to run the JVM in headless mode by adding -Djava.awt.headless=true to the command-line right after `java`. You can achieve this programmatically also - more details here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/headless-136834.html